# Auto Batch Process - Trim, change bit rate and then normalize wav files via sox on Windows

Tags: batch-file, wav, sox

I would like to batch process wav files in a folder:

1. Firstly trimming the files to 5secs and placing the trimmed files in a folder called "Trim5s", then
2. Changing the bit rate on the trimmed files (that is in the folder "Trim5s") and saving the new bit rate files derived from the trimmed files in Step 1 above to a folder called "16bit" and then
3. Normalize the new trimmed + new bitrate files to -1 that is in the "16bit" folder derived in Step 2 above and saving the normalied + trimmed files + new bitrate files to a folder "Norm-1".

This is my folder structure:

```
MainFolder
   |____file1.wav
   |____file2.wav
   |____Trim5s
           |____file1_trim5s.wav
           |____file2_trim5s.wav
           |____16bit
                  |____file1_trim5s_16bit.wav
                  |____file2_trim5s_16bit.wav
                  |____Norm-1
                         |____file1_trim5s_16bit_Norm-1.wav
                         |____file2_trim5s_16bit_Norm-1.wav
```

Currently I do the steps manually each time for each step.  Here are the Windows `cmd` commands:

Step 1: Trim files to  secs:

```
for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S "%i" "Trim5s\%~ni_trim5.wav" trim 0 5
```

I then manually change the directory to "Trim5s" and run the second step:

Step 2: Change bit depth to 16bits in the "Trim5s" folder:

```
for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S "%i" -b 16 "16bit\%~ni_16bit.wav"
```

Then I manually change the directory again to the folder "16bit" and run the third step:

Step 3: Normalize files in the 16bit folder:

```
for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S --norm=-1 "%i" "Norm-1\%~ni_norm-1.wav"
```

Is there a way to automate this process where I can automatically do all 3 process?  That is, convert the three manual steps given above to a nested loop?   Can the nested loop be accomplished or is there a better approach to carry out the 3 tasks mentioned above automatically from the MainFolder?

This is what I tried so far:

```
for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S "%i" "Trim5s\%~ni_trim-5.wav" trim 0 0.5 & cd Trim5s & for %j in (*.wav) do sox -S "%j" -b 16 "..\16bit\%~nj_16bit.wav" & cd 16bit & for %k in (*wav) do sox -S --norm=-1 "%k" "..\norm-1\%~nk_norm-1.wav"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [batch convert in parallel data using sox - change bit depth AND normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65188633/batch-convert-in-parallel-data-using-sox-change-bit-depth-and-normalize)

Comment: @MartinZeitler, No, that post will be deleted as some progress was made since then to get to this point.

Comment: You could have simply edited it, instead of duplicating yourself.

Comment: What have you tried on your own so far, and where are you stuck? You are not new here, so you should be well aware that this site is not a free code/script writing service, and that "is there a way" questions are not quite well received here…

Comment: This is a [[tag:batch-file]] question, so why not take your invalid and unnecessary single line [[tag:cmd]] example, and break it down into a multiline parenthesized block for running in a batch file. It will make it much simpler for us and yourself to follow your individual steps like that. You can read how to use a [tag:for-loop] in a batch script, by opening a [tag:command-prompt] window, typing `for /?`, and pressing the `[ENTER]` key.

Comment: @Joe I edited my answer with `Invoke-Command` instead of  `Trim` everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few comments:

- it's a good idea to work with absolute path rather than "relative path and change the current/working directory" because when things go wrong, one get lost in those working directories; absolute path also allows to chain scripts straightforwardly.
- It's also a good idea to avoid to chain subfolders, because you're creating a chain of dependencies, which can be hard to follow/test when one change the script or add new ones; this reduces the maintenance overhead/cost. Nevertheless, if you want to do it, feel free to change the target directories in the script.
- It's a good idea to define functions in a script, this improves the readability and improves the testability, and allows reusability.

In this script I define first few functions for solving small problems and at the end, it's the actual batch processing:

```
function ToColor($color) { process { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor $color } }
function Trim($source, $target) { "sox -S $source $target trim 0 5" | ToColor "green" }
function To16bits($source, $target) { "sox -S $source -b 16 $target" | ToColor "green" }
function Norm($source, $target) { "sox -S --norm=-1 $source $target" | ToColor "green" }
function AddTag($ori, $tag) { return $ori.name -replace '(\w+)(\.wav)', ('$1_' + $tag + '$2') }
function AddDir($ori, $name) { New-Item -Path $ori -Name $name -ItemType "directory" -Erroraction SilentlyContinue }

function Batch($func, $oriSubDir, $newDir, $tag) {
    AddDir $dir $newDir
    $oriDir = "$dir$oriSubDir"
    $targetDir = "$dir$newDir"
    $files = Get-ChildItem *.wav -Path $oriDir
    "applying <<$tag>> to $(($files | Measure-Object).Count) files from <$oriDir> to <$targetDir>" | ToColor "yellow"
    foreach($file in $files) {
        $target = AddTag $file $tag
        Invoke-Command $func -ArgumentList "$oriDir/$file", "$targetDir/$target"
        New-Item -Path "$targetDir" -ItemType "file" -Name $target # mocks creation of processed file
    }
}

function ProcessFiles() {
    foreach ($dir in $targetList) {
        "using original files from $dir" | ToColor "yellow"
        Batch ${function:Trim}     ""       "trim5s" "trim"
        Batch ${function:To16bits} "trim5s" "16bits" "16bits"
        Batch ${function:Norm}     "16bits" "Norm-1" "norm"
    }
}

$targetList = $args | Where-Object {Test-Path $_  -PathType Container}
$count = ($targetList | Measure-Object).Count
if($count -eq 0) {
    "usage: Start-BatchSox.ps1 dir1 [dir2 ...]" | ToColor "yellow"
    return
}
"Got $count directories to process" | ToColor "yellow"
ProcessFiles
```

In order to have the actual behavior, you need to comment the `New-Item` line and change the process command (as text) to actual command, eg.,

```
"sox -S $source $target trim 0 5" | ToColor "green"
```

to:

```
sox -S $source $target trim 0 5
```

The script can be put in `Start-BatchSox.ps1` which can be put somewhere in your path; then you can call it from anywhere (see the "usage" message).